# Trying to understand Ext.require, Ext.class.requires, and Ext.Loader

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

So I've inherited this extjs 4.1.3 project and I'm trying to understand it.

I've noticed that there are both Ext.require and Ext.define requires EVERYWHERE. The code is made of a lot of boilerplate code from sencha docs and I feel there is a lot of redundancy. It makes a whole lot of clutter and I feel like its wrong that when I add a file, I have to add it more than once (to Ext.require and Ext.define requires).

Couple of questions:

1) How can I tell if a require is actually ... required? From my understanding, it only tells the web page to load something now or later (this might be related to question 3). Am I guaranteed to see warnings from Ext saying "you should include abc" if those files are needed?

2) Is there any difference between Ext.require and Ext.define requires? Do I need both? If I only need one, is one more "standard" than the other?

3) What exactly does "Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled: true});" do? I am guessing that lets ext dynamically load things if I don't specifically require them. Shouldn't I not need requires at all then? I'm not saying this is good practice, but is it true? Actually, if anything, isn't using this bad practice? You'll end up losing track of dependencies if you don't have them written down. Or do you "trust" Ext.Loader to take care of everything relating to dependencies so that you don't even have to worry about it.

The reason I ask because I thought this was true, but after the below experience, I am thinking it is not.

I thought I figured this out, but apparently my interpretation of Ext.Loader (Question 3) is wrong because if I comment out all of my requires, I get

```
[07:15:05.577] Error: [Ext.createByAlias] Cannot create an
instance of unrecognized alias: layout.border
```

If I take out 'Ext.layout.*. How come this isn't loaded dynamically if have Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled: true})?

**TLDR:** I don't know when it is safe/good practice to use Ext.require/Ext.define requires. If I don't see any warnings and my app works, does that mean I'm good or is there still a chance something is being "loaded" as well as it could be? And what does Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled: true}) do?

EDIT: Here is an example: the app.js file. It just feels to wordy doesn't it?

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled: true});

Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', 'ux');

Ext.require([
'Ext.layout.*',
'Ext.ux.*',
'Ext.grid.*',
'APP.controller.Controller',
'APP.view.MapPanel',
'APP.view.FilterPanel',
'APP.view.Viewport'
]);

var start_app = function() {

var app = Ext.application({
    name: 'APP',
    appFolder: 'app',
    requires: [
    ],
    autoCreateViewport: true,
    uses: [
        'APP.controller.Controller',
        'APP.view.MapPanel',
        'APP.view.FilterPanel',
        'APP.view.Viewport'
    ],
    launch: function() {

    },
    controllers: [
        'APP.controller.Controller'
    ]
});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the above code you only need `controllers:['Controller']`. In turn, in the controller file you need `views:[]`, `stores:[]` and `models:[]` depending on what you want the controller to pull from the server.

Another example: Let's say you code a grid and it uses number column, so you need `requires:['Ext.grid.column.Number'` in the grid config.

What I do is that I put there minimum I think is required, and then I watch the console. Either I get an error and I fix it or I get "Synchronous Loading" warning that I also fix.

For more details see: http://www.sencha.com/blog/countdown-to-ext-js-4-dynamic-loading-and-new-class-system

Comment: Is there any "standard" for using require vs requires? When to use Ext.require([]) vs Ext.whatever({ requires:[]})

Comment: The logic is: 'a component/class "requires" another classes' so if this relation is known, then use `requires:[]`. Otherwise use `Ext.require()` - I need it very very rarely.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused. I understand the logic of "requiring" something, but when is "require" different than "requires." What do you mean by "if this relation is known?" By the way, thank you very much for helping!

Comment: If you declare `requires:[]` on a component or a class and Ext starts to execute `Ext.define` and it finds that some (or all) other classes listed in `requires:[]` are not loaded, then define is suspended, required classes are loaded (btw, internally using `Ext.require()`) and then the define is resumed. If you call require manually, the classes you pass as argument are just loaded without any relation to anything. Please note that loading is asynchronous.

Comment: So requires seems more dynamic than require. Thank you!

Comment: A little late, but I understand what you meant in your earlier replies. If the js file needs an extjs class, use Ext.require(). If a extJS class needs an extjs class, use the requires property.